# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a UEFI system without touching the UEFI bootloader configuration?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, grub-efi

I've got a laptop configured to dual-boot Windows 10 and Gentoo that I want to add an Ubuntu installation to so that I can do firmware updates (the OEM currently only supports handling of firmware updates on Ubuntu and Ubuntu derivatives).

In this particular case, I'm not directly using the UEFI boot manager other than having it load GRUB2 both because the system in question doesn't provide the option of a menu with a timeout (you have to hit F12 to get a boot menu, and it sits there until you select something), and because I want passwords on some boot options but not others (and Windows is one of the things I want a boot password for).  I would like to keep this setup and integrate Ubuntu into it, instead of having to deal with the (crappy) UEFI boot manager interface when I want to boot Ubuntu, which in turn means I need a way for Ubuntu to not mess with the UEFI boot manager variables (fighting with Windows every time it gets upgraded to a new build is bad enough without another OS contending for control).

Based on what I've seen so far it looks like the only way to do this is to do a non-EFI install of Ubuntu, and then pull in the `grub-efi` package manually (and probably do some trickery to keep `efibootmgr` from being run).  Is there any other way to do this without needing to create a custom installer or custom `grub-efi` package?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand UEFI... With UEFI all OSes can be booted independently. Let's suppose you currently have CentOS as the first boot priority and that boots to Grub where you have the option to also boot Windows (typical dual boot configuration). Adding Ubuntu to the equation doesn't change that.

Comment: @MichaelBay That assumes that you have a system which has a proper UEFI boot manager, and this one does not (you can't get a boot menu except by hitting F12, which is not an option for me because I switch back and forth between Windows and Linux pretty frequently).

Comment: Any UEFI system has a proper boot manager, UEFI *is* a boot manager. What you did when installing both OSes may make it harder than it should be, like having one of the OSes (Cent, most likely) installed in legacy mode. Either way installing Ubuntu changes nothing in the equation. More information here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: @MichaelBay A proper UEFI boot manager implementation provides a way to set up a menu of boot options that comes up automatically on boot and selects the first item in the boot order by default after a configurable timeout (that is, it gives you the ability to get a menu just like GRUB provides, without needing GRUB), Very few systems actually provide that, despite it being part of the specification (kind of like how the EFI RTC isn't implemented correctly on some systems).

Comment: That is NOT typical in any consumer grade PCs. And, again, being that the case or not, adding Ubuntu changes nothing. If you're dual booting via Grub you'll be doing the same but now with the possibility to choose which of the Linux distros is in control of said Grub.

Comment: @MichaelBay And making sure Ubuntu _isn't_ in control of GRUB is what this is about.  It's installed in a non-standard manner in a non-standard location, so the only issue is making sure that Ubuntu doesn't update the EFI boot manager variables to change the boot order.

Comment: Like with **any other installation in UEFI mode**, Ubuntu will add EFI entries, it will not change the boot default but even if it did that's a moot point (and, of course, you have the option to not even install Ubuntu's Grub). **You can always, at any time, set UEFI to boot from what it booting before**. Assuming it was CentOS' Grub just choose the CentOS EFI entry again. Whether or not you then update that Grub to include Ubuntu is up to you . This, of course, assumes all OSes are installed as they should be, in UEFI mode. Over and out.

Comment: Every new UEFI install typically updates UEFI to make its entry first. But just use efibootmgr to change boot order. What brand/model system. We like to know, so others with same or similar systems will know issues. You can install Ubuntu without installing grub. Use `ubiquity -b` in terminal.  But best to have all systems in UEFI boot mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, and all the pieces in place, assuming you don't want secure boot enabled (which would take the ...signed versions of the kernel...).  Just install Ubuntu in legacy mode, no UEFI variables are touched, no UEFI files/directories are created.  Reboot Gentoo and run sudo update-grub to pick up the Ubuntu installation in the grub menu.  Now you can boot the Ubuntu installation in UEFI mode -- it doesn't need another UEFI grub, you've already got one.  If you want, you can actually add the fstab entry to mount the EFI partition at /boot/efi, but really, without a grub-efi, why bother (note, I have a system which I did exactly the above, but I did add the fstab entry, in case I ever wanted to install the grub-efi (I never did install it)..).

The system I am running has a legacy Windows/Ubuntu on disk one, and an UEFI Ubuntu on disk 2.  I install Disk 2 in legacy mode,manually creating an EFI partition, which I populated from a backup off another system.  One edit of the UUID in the grub.cfg stub to pick up the maintained /boot/grub/grub.cfg, and the second disk boots in UEFI mode by selecting the disk.  In your case, your existing installations are already in UEFI mode, so the existing grub can do everything.